# macro to download selected messages attachments - Problem about downloaded files count

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros, vba, attachments

I changed some codes for getting selected messages attachments to my hard drive like below :

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem 'Object
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim I As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String
Dim Counter As Long

strFolderpath = "D:\attachments"
If (Dir$(strFolderpath, vbDirectory) = "") Then
    MsgBox "'" & strFolderpath & "'  not exist"
    MkDir strFolderpath
    MsgBox "'" & strFolderpath & "'  we create it"

Else
    MsgBox "'" & strFolderpath & "'  exist"
End If

    ' Get the path to your My Documents folder
    'strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
    strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\"
    On Error Resume Next

    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' The attachment folder needs to exist
' You can change this to another folder name of your choice

    ' Set the Attachment folder.
    strFolderpath = strFolderpath

    ' Check each selected item for attachments.
    Counter = 1
    For Each objMsg In objSelection

    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    ' Use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.

    For I = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    ' Get the file name.
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(I).FileName

    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & Counter & "_" & strFile

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(I).SaveAsFile strFile
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Next I
    End If

    Next

ExitSub:

Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
    MsgBox "All Selected Attachments Have Been Downloaded ..."
End Sub
```

my goal email uses imap service...

this vb codes works perfect!

but my problem is when download is finished we have not needed files in attachments folder!
I have 450 **UNREAD** emails in my inbox that all of them have attachmen/s...
but we have only 200 files in attachments folder! (created by upper codes)
how can I fix this issue?
it seems this problem is in relationship with Unread Messages And My ADSL speed (but it should n't , I don't know?!)
when u read an email it seems Outlook does some stuff with that email and so next time that email runs faster because of it's caching.
how can I do this job for my unread emails with upper codes?
or is there any idea about this problem?

> at last I would be really appreciate
>   for review and add or correct my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of the attachments have the same name they might be getting overwritten (cant remember if `.SaveAsFile` will just overwrite or cause an error), so you might want to check if the filename exists first, or add some other identifier to the filename (maybe the message subject?).

Outlook can be set to do different things with email accounts using IMAP, such as downloading just the headers, and getting the whole message only when you open it, or downloading the whole message in the first place.

Can you do some random checks to see if attachments from messages that were read all exist, and no attachments from unread messages exist? That would confirm the IMAP theory, and might be able to be fixed in the code with a method to download selected messages if they aren't already.

Comment: thanks for answer / .SaveAsFile will just overwrite -> i had been added a counter to my code -> plz see is it ok? (there are many attachments with a same name) besides i test my emails for random -> they are ok -> but some of them have no file after vba END / would u plz give me some codes about -> "able to be fixed in the code with a method to download selected messages if they aren't already."

Comment: You will need to loop through the selected messages again, before you start getting the attachments, and check if objMsg.DownloadState = OlDownloadState.olHeaderOnly, and if so, set objMsg.MarkForDownload = OlRemoteStatus.olMarkedForDownload. Then after that loop, I guess tell outlook to  download messages or something, I dont know how to do this.

Comment: Voting to move to stackoverflow, where it will get more views.